# org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity com.oberon.fm.domain.User

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-neo4j

I wannt to create data on neo4jdb,but it does not work well.It disturb me somedays,Im apprecicated for someone can help me!

error info

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Unknown persistent entity com.oberon.fm.domain.User
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:177)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:140)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getPersistentEntity(Neo4jTemplate.java:663)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:541)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getMappingPolicy(Neo4jTemplate.java:718)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:357)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:351)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator.populateWithSomeTestData(DatabasePopulator.java:43)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9138765.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$945b6135.populateWithSomeTestData(<generated>)
at com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController.populate(AuthController.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16:02:02.918 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
16:02:02.921 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController@15830d2]: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
16:02:02.923 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController@15830d2]: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
16:02:02.923 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController@15830d2]: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
16:02:02.928 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1024) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:521) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) ~[spring-aop-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.oberon.fm.neo4j.service.DatabasePopulator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$945b6135.populateWithSomeTestData(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.oberon.fm.controller.AuthController.populate(AuthController.java:26) ~[AuthController.class:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177) ~[spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) [catalina.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolled back
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.rollbackCommit(TxManager.java:629) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:390) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:123) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.BaseSpringTransactionImpl.commit(BaseSpringTransactionImpl.java:66) ~[neo4j-kernel-2.1.5.jar:2.1.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1021) ~[spring-tx-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

my service code

```
@Service
public class DatabasePopulator {
@Autowired
Neo4jTemplate template;

private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(DatabasePopulator.class);

@Transactional
public void populateWithSomeTestData() {
    System.out.println("==== Populating ====");
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = template.getGraphDatabaseService();

    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();

    try {
        User user = new User("micha", "Micha", "password",
                 User.Roles.ROLE_USER);
        User me = template.save(user);
        User ollie = template.save(new User("ollie", "Olliver", "password",
                User.Roles.ROLE_USER));
        me.addFriend(ollie);

        // id and title
        Movie forrestGump = template.save(new Movie("1", "Forrest Gump"));

        me.rate(template, forrestGump, 5, "Best of the series");

        tx.success();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        tx.close();
    }
}
```

my user model

```
  @NodeEntity
public class User {
@GraphId Long nodeId;
public static final String SALT = "cewuiqwzie";
public static final String FRIEND = "FRIEND";
public static final String RATED = "RATED";
@Indexed
String login;
String name;
String password;
String info;
private Roles[] roles;
public User(String login, String name, String password, Roles... roles) {
    this.login = login;
    this.name = name;
    this.password = encode(password);
    this.roles = roles;
}

private String encode(String password) {
    return new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(password, SALT);
}

@RelatedToVia(type = RATED)
@Fetch Iterable<Rating> ratings;

@RelatedTo(type = RATED)
Set<Movie> favorites;


@RelatedTo(type = FRIEND, direction = Direction.BOTH)
@Fetch Set<User> friends;

public void addFriend(User friend) {
    this.friends.add(friend);
}

public Rating rate(Neo4jOperations template, Movie movie, int stars, String comment) {
    final Rating rating = template.createRelationshipBetween(this, movie, Rating.class, RATED, false).rate(stars, comment);
    return template.save(rating);
}

public Collection<Rating> getRatings() {
    return IteratorUtil.asCollection(ratings);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s (%s)", name, login);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Set<User> getFriends() {
    return friends;
}

public Roles[] getRole() {
    return roles;
}


public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getInfo() {
    return info;
}
public void setInfo(String info) {
    this.info = info;
}
public void updatePassword(String old, String newPass1, String newPass2) {
    if (!password.equals(encode(old))) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Existing Password invalid");
    if (!newPass1.equals(newPass2)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("New Passwords don't match");
    this.password = encode(newPass1);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isFriend(User other) {
    return other!=null && getFriends().contains(other);
}

public enum Roles implements GrantedAuthority {
    ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User user = (User) o;
    if (nodeId == null) return super.equals(o);
    return nodeId.equals(user.nodeId);

}

public Long getId() {
    return nodeId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return nodeId != null ? nodeId.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
}
```

}

my context-neo4j.groovy

```
beans {
xmlns neo4j: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"

neo4j."config"("storeDirectory" : "../NEO4JDB_ZDL")
neo4j."repositories"("base-package" : "com.oberon.fm")
```

}

my context-mvc.groovy

```
beans {
xmlns context: "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

/*context."component-scan"("base-package" : "com.oberon.fm") {
 'exclude-filter'('type': "annotation", 'expression': "org.springframework.stereotype.Controller")
 }*/
context."component-scan"("base-package" : "com.oberon.fm")

viewResolver(InternalResourceViewResolver) {
    prefix = "/pages/"
    suffix = ".jsp"
}
```

}

Comment: Did you declare this entity in the file `persistence.xml`?

Comment: my db is neo4j,and i did not use persistence,i just want add some testdata to neo4j

Comment: i have solved my problem.the config of spring data neo4j is different between 2.0and3.3    neo4j."config"("storeDirectory" : "../NEO4JDB_ZDL","base-package" : "com.oberon.fm.domain")